# Can I create constructor for Enum?

Tags: c#, .net

I have written below code and it's compiling successfully.

```
class Program
{
        enum Fruits
        {
            Apple,
            Mango,
            Banana
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Fruits f = new Fruits();
        }
}
```

Despite of `Fruits` being an `enum`, compiler and interpreter are allowing me to write this. Does this mean I can create a constructor for an enum? if yes then how?

Comment: what would you like to accomplish with such constructor?

Comment: I might want to override it's default behavior of returning Apple by default, just thinking out loud.

Comment: You can change which is default by changing the order that the enum alternatives are listed.

Comment: I don't think so. Even with inheritance, `Enum` is `sealed` so you can not have a superclass inheriting from `Fruits`.

Comment: After a little time in Swift, I miss things like this.  In my case, I'm writing a new enum which classifies values from another larger enum.  Say FruitFamily and Fruit.  I'd love to be able to write `var family = FruitFamily(someFruit)`.

Answer (score 7):

No, you can't.

`new Fruits()` will return the default value (the value corresponding to `0` in the underlying type of the enum), it's the same as `default(Fruits)` (or `Fruits.Apple` in your case).

Remeber that enums are only wrappers around a primitive type (`int` by default). You can pretty much compare `new Fruits()` to `new int()`.

Usually you don't use the `new Fruits()`/`new int()` syntax as it's more common to just write `0` or `default(T)`, but you may want to use it in generic code. As an example:

```
public T NewInstance<T>()
    where T : new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

You are allowed to call `NewInstance<Fruits>()`, which will return `Fruits.Apple`.

Comment: Syntactic Sugar to `int`

Comment: `int()` works in .NET 1.0, prior to generics. It's an advantage, but not a reason.

Comment: @Jon Thanks for your input, I totally forgot .NET 1.0. I reworded the answer.

Answer (score 4):

[C# Spec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx):

> An enum type is a distinct value type with a set of named constants.

As for the default value (as explained in the other answer):

> The default value of any enum type is the integral value zero
>   converted to the enum type. In cases where variables are automatically
>   initialized to a default value, this is the value given to variables
>   of enum types. In order for the default value of an enum type to be
>   easily available, the literal 0 implicitly converts to any enum type.

Move the default constant to be the first in your enum.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Check out the IL output (generated in LINQPad).  It's not actually calling a constructor at all.  Instead, it's storing the integer value 0 inside a local variable called `f`.  This is the *exact same output* as you get when you use a type cast to the enum.

As far as the compiler is concerned, `Fruits f = new Fruits();` is the same as `Fruit f = (Fruit)0;`.

`Fruits f = new Fruits()` IL

```
Program.Main:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // f
IL_0003:  ret         

Program..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  ret
```

For comparison, here's the IL output of a normal class.  Look at IL_001 under Program.Main where it actually calls a constructor for the class.

```
Program.Main:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  newobj      UserQuery+Program+Fruits..ctor
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // f
IL_0007:  ret         

Program..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  ret         

Fruits..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  ret
```

Answer (score 1):

For any value type, there is a parameterless constructor that returns the all-zero value. Hence:

```
var val = new int(); // 0
var val = new double(); // 0.0
var val = new DateTime(); // 0001-01-01T00:00:00.000000 Unspecified timezone
var val = new StringSplitOptions(); // StringSplitOptions.None
```

However:

1. You cannot add a new constructor for a type that isn't a `struct` or a `class`, and so as far as value-types go, only `struct`.
2. You cannot change the implementation of any of these default constructors.

In the case of `enum`s and primitives the constructor isn't even declared.

Hence you can't create such a constructor.

(Strictly speaking, .NET does allow you to set a defined parameterless constructor on a `struct` but C# doesn't, and if you do it in raw CIL there are inconsistent rules as to when it will be called and when you'll just get an all-zero instance created).