# How to prevent enum constructors

Tags: c#, enums

I was surprised, but enums can be created with constructor in C#.
For example, I have the enum:

```
public enum Color
{
    White = 1,
    Red = 2
}
```

Then it could be created like this:

```
var color = new Color();
```

And the value will be 0, which is actually not valid enum value.

So, can we prohibit enum constructors somehow? Any other ideas how to avoid this?

Thanks.

Comment: `var color = (Color)125;` is perfectly legal, too. You have to manually check whether the value is valid when reading the enum variable...

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182149.aspx Why do you need to assign values to a non-flag enum?

Comment: 0 is the default for any value type whether it's valid or not and can't be changed. What are you using the enum for? Maybe if we had more context we could suggest an alternative.

Comment: As a hacky way to solve this you can use a code analyzer to get an error for Enum constructor

Comment: A similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31834955/can-i-create-constructor-for-enum. Enums doesn't have default constructor, it just wrapper of underlying int values and determines default value by a value corresponding to zero.

Comment: @PaulF I do not want to do it. I want to prevent doing it.

Comment: @OlegDudnyk: my question was why you assigned vales to your enums - why not just leave them as the defaults? Is there a specific reason why White must equal 1 & Red = 2?

Comment: @PaulF It's useful if the enum represents statuses that are serialized somehow. We have value-specified enums for statuses saved as numbers in database data. Flags specifically mean multiple values can be combined, which is a whole different case.

Comment: @Nyerguds: I am just trying to understand why the OP is trying to avoid the documented behaviour of the language. Simply declaring an enum variable _"Color color;"_ would have exactly the same effect an enum with default value of 0 - it is not an effect of the _"var color = new Color();"_ style of declaration.

Comment: You cannot do that with enum, but you can create your own custom class ("type-safe enum") and restrict its possible values.

Answer (score 9):

> So, can we prohibit enum constructors somehow?

No. The problem is not strictly related to the constructor itself: `(Color)0` is valid too, since the underlying type can have the value `0`.

> Any other ideas how to avoid this?

No, this is basically a broader problem. The only way you can prevent this is by checking your input values on validness.

You should always have a `0` enum value according to [Code Analysis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182149.aspx).

Comment: You don't even need to cast `0` to assign it to an enum.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Agreed, but else the code sample would be hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way to avoid it in general. You can have a static analyzer warn, but it doesn’t solve the underlying problem that an enum is just a number and as such it can have the value 123. More commonly it will have the value zero (for example if you new it, or don’t assign it).

To see the problem more clearly, consider this:

```
var colors = new Color[100];
```

What is `colors[0]` now? It’s zero, like any uninitialized number. So an enum allows you to give names to values - it does *not* guarantee that variables of the type uses one of those named values.

A good best practice is to always have a names value for zero in your enum (typically in this case it would be called “None”, “Uninitialised”, “NotSet” or similar). Once you have that, the uninitialized values will make sense.

Answer (score 1):

`public enum Color` is actually the shortened form of the full declaration of an enum, which would be `public enum Color : int`.

An enum *always* has an underlying base type, and is technically simply a variable of that type. By default, this type is 32-bit integer, meaning any 32-bit integer can be assigned to such an enum.

The actual enum definitions are merely named members of that type for easy use in programming, allowing you to change or even completely ignore the underlying values without any need to change the code.

But internally, all enums of your type `Color` (terrible name, by the way) are just Int32 values, and [as Anders Forsgren pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47914118/395685), like any other Int32 value, they will default to 0 in arrays and any kind of global variables. This is also the reason why the official guidelines recommend always putting a 0 definition in your enum.